# How to POST request while exposing localhost using localtunnel

Tags: javascript, node.js, localtunnel

I'm using node js as server. Do i have to configure index.js file while using localtunnel?
While submitting form, which URL do I have to specify? should i use URL provided by localtunnel.

```
<form name="formname" action="http://localhost:3000/register" method="post">
```

I know its a silly question. Can somebody provide a small guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your routes are set up, you should just be able to post to `/register` like so:

`<form name="formname" action="/register" method="post">`

EDIT: Wanted to add, if you're developing in a JS environment like node, you should consider having the form action being triggered with an event listener (syntax depending on if you're using jQuery / vue.js / React / Polymer etc) that:

1. prevents the default submit action.
2. makes an asynchronous call to the backend using AJAX.
3. triggers some sort of re-rendering, if you're using ES5 you'll pass a call back function, or if you're using ES6 you can use the promise chain.

Comment: Thank you so much...   Changed URL to action="/register" Its working....

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, Issuing the below command will give you a randomized subdomain URL which you can make use of too.

```
lt –port 80
```

which will generate a URL like,

https://somerandomizedstring.localtunnel.me

And in your case you can use the generated URL+/regstier in your `<form>` tag's action, For example,

```
<form name="formname" action="https://somerandomizedstring.localtunnel.me/register" method="post">
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @BlackHeart :-)